# Lightweight approach for providing a simple web-based interface to a Java class, minimizing startup overhead?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I've been looking for a way to provide a simple web-based interface for a Java class.  I guess one way to use one of the lightweight Java-based servers to frontend this Java class, but there's a twist to my situation.

The thing is that this class has quite a large startup overhead, because when it starts up, it pulls a bunch of information from a remote database.

Because of this, it would not be practical to instantiate the class for each request.

So I was wondering what kind of design would make sense for this type of situation?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Does the output depend on any input? Can you get away with old/cached information?

Comment: So don't launch the service separately for each request?

Comment: Are you using the SpringFramework?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to pull that data in the class. As instead, you can create a different class that will query the data and keep it. Then you can use that class to retrieve the data without that much overhead.

I call this the *Glob Approach*

---

```
public class Glob {

    // Data
    private static MyReallyBigData data = null;

    // Just to make sure that stuff loaded only one time.
    private static boolean loadedYet;

    // Getter for data;
    public static MyReallyBigData getData() {
        checkLoadedYet();
        return data;
    }

    // Check if the data is loaded of not. If not, then load it.
    private static void checkLoadedYet() {
        if (!loadedYet) {
            loadData();
        }
    }

    // This loads the data.
    private void loadData() {
        // Perform business action here and 
        // assign the values.
    }

}
```

Then in your concerned class, you can do something like this:

```
public class MyReallyImportantClass {

    public MyReallyImportantClass() {
        MyReallyBigData data = Glob.getData();
    }

}
```

And you will feel the difference :)

---

I have some links for you that you might wanna check.

- [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39411681/use-property-at-startup-to-determine-which-section-of-code-to-run)
- [This Google Search](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=l_rSV5jSK6TG8Aef6I3wDQ#q=singleton%20design%20pattern)
- [This Google Search](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=l_rSV5jSK6TG8Aef6I3wDQ#q=object%20pooling%20in%20java)
- [This small code from my public repo](https://github.com/JExaples/quicklooks/tree/master/basic-object-pool)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Vert.x, you can set it up as another Verticle, and communicate with it using EventBus.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    vertx.deployVerticle(new ServerVerticle());
    vertx.deployVerticle(new HeavyDutyVerticle());

}


/**
 * Static only for the sake of example
 */
static class HeavyDutyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() {

        // Do some heavy initializing here
        // ...

        // Your server will call this part
        vertx.eventBus().consumer("processMessage", (request) -> {
            // Do something smart

            // Reply
            request.reply("Something smart");
        });
    }
}

private static class ServerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() {

        Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        router.get("/").handler((request) -> {
            vertx.eventBus().send("processMessage", null, (heavyDutyResponse) -> {
                if (heavyDutyResponse.succeeded()) {
                    request.response().end("Said something");
                }
                // Handle errors
            });
        });


        // This is your Hub
        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8888);
    }
}
```