# Use property at startup to determine which section of code to run

Tags: java, design-patterns

There is a debug level being set in a config file. We grab that value at store it in a variable on a class and use that value from there on out. It is hit roughly 500-4000 times during server startup, depending on the environment.

Is there a common work around or design pattern that would allow us to get that value at the beginning and then run the code base depending on its value? The end end goal would be to not have to query that parameter from the other class 400-4000 times during startup in an if statement to decide if we are supposed to log a statement or not depending on the debug level being used.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Show us some code with some simple and minimum example please.

Comment: Did you know AOP?

Comment: The Class that stores the debug level should be the same Class that writes the log. It is its own responsability to check the desired level and and act accordingly to it. Do you know log4j, slf4j, etc? There are logging apis that makes our life easier

Comment: We are using log4j, but all over the code we check the system property and if that property is the right one for a section of code, we run it. I just want to avoid even having to check the value since we know exactly what debug level we have set.

Answer (score 0):

I call this "*The Glob Pattern*". I had a similar trouble as you as the lead application architect of an enterprise scale application (Over 10000 source files).

The solution of this is very simple. I have a properties file like this.

```
################################################
########## APPLICATION SETTINGS ################
################################################
appname                 = ${ecommfy.appname}
rootpath                = ${project.tomcat.directory}/webapps/${ecommfy.appname}
host                    = ${ecommfy.host}
appath                  = ${ecommfy.appath}

isSTAGING               = ${ecommfy.staging}
dbname                  = ${ecommfy.database.name}
dburl                   = ${ecommfy.database.url}
dbuser                  = ${ecommfy.database.username}
dbpass                  = ${ecommfy.database.password}
dbdriver                = ${ecommfy.database.driver}
adminSupportLanguage    = ${ecommfy.adminSupportLanguage}
```

And a class like this:

```
public class Glob {

    protected final static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(Glob.class);  

    /*
     * ====================================================
     *          GLOB VARIABLES
     * ====================================================
     */
    private static boolean notLoadedYet                 = true;
    private static final String sep                     = java.io.File.separator;
    private static String fname                         = null;

    /*
     * ====================================================
     *          STATIC VARIABLES
     * ====================================================
     */
    private static String rootpath                      = "";
    private static String host                          = "";
    private static String contenthost                   = "";
    private static String serverprefix                  = "";
    private static String appname                       = "";
    private static String appath                        = "";
    private static String dburl                         = "";
    private static String dbuser                        = "";
    private static String dbpass                        = "";
    private static String dbdriver                      = "";
    private static String dataSourceLive                = "";
    private static String dataSouceStaging              = "";
    private static String defualtLanguageForAdmin       = "en";

    /*
     * ======================================================
     *          GLOB UTILITY MEHTODS
     * ======================================================
     */
    private static void checkLoadedYet() {
        if (notLoadedYet) {
            notLoadedYet = loadFromFile();
        }
    }

    private static boolean loadFromFile() {

        InputStream fstream = null;

        try {           
            Method method = null;
            method = Thread.class.getMethod("getContextClassLoader", new Class[]{});
            ClassLoader classLoader = (ClassLoader) method.invoke(Thread.currentThread(), new Object[]{});

            fstream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("eCommFy.properties");

            if (fstream != null)
                fname = "eCommFy.properties";

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(fstream);

            readApplicationProperties(properties);

            fstream.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("EC203: Error opening eCommFy.properties!", ex);
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static void readApplicationProperties(Properties props) {

        logger.info("Start Reading Application Proeprties...");

        // Business Action

        logger.info("Done reading application properties...");

    }

}
```

The idea behind Glob is that it reads the properties file while getting a variable. This properties file is read only one time and then you can use the `Glob` to make decisions that affect the flow. Currently, we are making huge decisions based on whether the application is running in the staging or the production environment.

---

We are totally `Spring` based and use `Maven` to manage builds. The `${ecommfy.appname}` notations are Maven properties that gets replaced when the application compiles.

---

The getter methods in glob look like this:

```
public static boolean isSTAGING() {
    checkLoadedYet();
    return isSTAGING;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the full extent of the problem, but I'll assume it boils down to something similar to this.

We have a system with various log severity levels: INFO, WARNING, ERROR

And a verbosity hierarchy:

- INFO: INFO, ERROR
- DEBUG: INFO, WARNING, ERROR

To solve this problem (in it's most basic form) we may define an interface for severities:

```
public interface SeverityLoggingStrategy {
    public void log(String msg);
}
```

A logger:

```
public class Logger {
    private SeverityLoggingStrategy infoSeverity;
    private SeverityLoggingStrategy warningSeverity;
    private SeverityLoggingStrategy errorSeverity;

    public Logger(SeverityLoggingStrategy infoSeverity, SeverityLoggingStrategy warningSeverity, SeverityLoggingStrategy errorSeverity)         { 
        //... 
    }

    public void info(String msg) {
        this.infoSeverity.log(msg);
    }
    public void warn(String msg) {
        this.warningSeverity.log(msg);
    }
    public void error(String msg) {
       this.errorSeverity.log(msg);
    }
}
```

Then we need at least 2 concrete severity logging strategies:

```
NonLoggingSeverityLoggingStrategy
LoggingSeverityLoggingStrategy
```

And finally a `LoggerFactory` that can assemble `SeverityLoggingStrategy`s into a `Logger` based on a verbosity level.

```
public class LoggerFactory {
    public forVerbosity(LogVerbosity verbosity) {
        if (verbosity == LogVerbosity.INFO) {
            return new Logger(
                new LoggingSeverityLoggingStrategy(),
                new NonLoggingSeverityLoggingStrategy(),
                new LoggingSeverityLoggingStrategy()
            );
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

When the system starts you can configure the right instance of the logger to use:

```
Logger logger = new LoggerFactory().forVerbosity(LogVerbosity.valueOf(config.logVerbosity()));
```

Then clients will be calling upon the logger using various log severity levels and the logger will use the appropriate logging strategy for the severity based on the configured verbosity.

```
logger.warn('some warning'); //delegates to NonLoggingSeverityLoggingStrategy in INFO verbosity mode
```

Obviously you may need more flexibility than this, but using the same approach while throwing in a few interfaces for more extension points you should be good to go.